# Ruby -- Outputting an element of an array within a hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am easily able to output the first element of the array ('student'). However, I am trying to get the second and third elements to be outputted.

The hash itself is: (At the moment there is only one key and the array is the only value)

```
student[name] = [test1, test2, test3]
```

The first line to output 'test1' is:

```
puts "#{student.keys.first} received #{student.values.first.first} in Test 1."
```

The second line to output 'test2' is:

```
puts "#{student.keys.first} received #{student.values.first(1)} in Test 2."
```

This last line isn't working for me. It simply displays all elements contained within the array. I only want it to display the second (index of 1).

Comment: You should access a hash by its keys, not by index.

Comment: Could you post an example for a typical `student` hash including keys and values?

Comment: `first[1]`, not `first(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo mistake.. change your brackets `()` to `[]`

```
puts "#{student.keys.first} received #{student.values.first[1]} in Test 2."
```

Try this in console:

```
student  = {'name' => ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']}
student.values.first[1]
#=> "test2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `student` begins as an empty hash and you then run `student[name] = [test1, test2, test3]`.

Then when you run `student.values.first` you will get `[test1, test2, test3]`. To retreive `test2` you can use `student.values.first[1]`.